# What has happened to SwingFXUtils?

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I just started using JavaFX 11, and SwingFXUtils seems to be gone (or renamed?)

I tried to download it manually, but the module-system complained about `import sun.awt.image.IntegerComponentRaster;`, and I couldn't get it to work.

I need to convert Swing Icon to JavaFX image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Java 9, `SwingFXUtils` has been moved to the `javafx.swing` module, under the package `javafx.embed.swing`.

See JavaFX 9 [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) and the new JavaFX 11 [Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html), hosted at https://openjfx.io.

If you have any issue with your sample, make sure you are adding the proper VM options. See the samples from the getting started [guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Probably you will need to add something like:

```
--module-path <path-to>/javafx-sdk-11/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.swing
```

Answer (score 1):

SwingFXUtils is still there if you have correctly added the javafx.swing module to your build path (see answer from José) but importing an internal class like `sun.awt.image.IntegerComponentRaster` is not allowed anymore.

To convert your icon you can try this:

```
Icon icon; // Your icon
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)((ImageIcon)icon).getImage();
WritableImage writable = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
```

Whether this works or not depends on how your icon was created but it is worth a try.

Comment: I needed to actually redraw the image into a BufferedImage, since the icon's image wasn't one.